# Is there a field in the Magento database which holds the date for when an order is shipped?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Is there a field in the Magento database which holds the date for when an order is shipped?

The only date fields I've come across are created_at and updated_at but i don't think that's what i need.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are many fields called `created_at` or `updated_at`, which table do you mean? Also, what version of Magento? Your question is tagged with both [tag:php] and [tag:mysql], what form are you expecting an answer in?

Answer (score 6):

First off, the hierarchy of objects/database tables surrounding orders underwent a major reorganization from EAV style objects to "flat" objects during the 1.4.x branch.  This specifics of this answer refer to **modern** versions of Magento.

When you create a shipment in Magento, you're creating a `sales/order_shipment` object.  These objects are stored in the `sales_flat_shipment` table.  This table has `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

Each of these order shipment objects links to a 1 or many **order shipment items** objects.  These objects are stored in the `sales_flat_shipment_item` table.  Each row in this table represents a shipped line item in the order.  This table links back to `sales_flat_shipment` by its `parent_id` column, and can be used to ensure a particular product, as well as its quantity, shipped.

Keep in mind that in most large scale e-commerce rollouts, Magento isn't the ultimate "source-of-truth" for what has and hasn't shipped.  Every ERP integration I've ever seen is a lump of undocumented custom code that's used to communicate with an oversold bit of warehouse management software. The above data is usually used as a flag to a larger system that an order is **ready** to ship.  Whether it has or not depends entirely on your process.

Comment: +1 for "lump", "undocumented" and "oversold". Never a truer word spoken.

Comment: Thanks for that thorough explanation Alan, great help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$shippingDate = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getCreatedAt()
```

Comes from the `sales_flat_shipment` table in the magento version i'm running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display actual shipping date then this date stored in '**sales_flat_shipment_grid**' table. You can fetch data from this table using Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_grid_collection');.

If you want to check then you can check from shipping grid at '**admin->sales->shipping**'.
If this one help full then please up vote. :)